# How to transmit a register value to parallel port using DOS interrupt?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, interrupt, x86-16

I have to understand a little concept for my work. I have to transmit the value stored in the register to parallel ports using DOS interrupt in Assembly language using 8086. Following is the tiny code that is needed to be clarified.

```
[org 0x0100]
mov AL, 01001011      ;any value in AL register that is to be transmitted
(...here...how to transmit it to parallel ports using DOS Interrupt?)
```

Comment: I can remember about 200 years ago I was using the printer ports 0x3BC and 0x378 for something similar, via `out`

Comment: may you please elaborate this sir, in keeping view the my code. thanks

Comment: INT 21h with AH=5 should output the character in DL to the printer (parallel port)

Comment: @ZeshanSajid, if **tofro**'s answer "worked" you should accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

INT 21h (DOS-Interrupt) with AH=5 should output the character in DL to the printer (parallel port)